# whether impala support java UDF in where clause

Tags: user-defined-functions, impala

I can use a java based UDF in hive and impala,but throw `ClassNotFound` error when call the udf in `where` clause

The UDF can not use when referenced in `where` clause but work properly when it only referenced behind `select` with impala 2.9.0-cdh5.12.1

In hive   `select udfjson(memo,state) from tableA where udfjson(memo,state) = 0 and name = 'test'`   is working properly but not in impala.

Execute         `select udfjson(memo,state) from tableA where name = 'test'` in impala is OK.         The UDF can use in impala only it not in `where` clause

here is the error

```
Error(255): Unknown error 255
Root cause: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSInputStream$ByteArrayStrategy
```

It's possible to referenced UDF in `where` clause with impala ?

Answer (score 1):

Use sub-query:

```
select * from
(
select udfjson(memo,state) as state from tableA where name = 'test'
)s
where s.state=0
```